# Unity/C# - Change size of brush for painting terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, terrain, heightmap

I'm coding an runtime terrain editor for unity and got stuck.
At first I wanted just to paint with textrue the terrain. I found this code and it worked fine:

SCRIPT: **TerrainPainter**

```
void Paint(Vector3 point)
{
    mapX = (int)(((point.x - terrainPosition.x) / terrainData.size.x) * heightmapWidth);
    mapY = (int)(((point.z - terrainPosition.z) / terrainData.size.z) * heigtmapHeight);

    splatmapData[mapY, mapX, 0] = element[0, 0, 0] = 0;
    splatmapData[mapY, mapX, 1] = element[0, 0, 1] = 1;

    terrain.terrainData.SetAlphamaps(mapX, mapY, element);
}
```

But now I want to paint with different sizes/thickness. I have another script, named Terrainmodifier, which I use to raise and lower the terrain. There I have this lines for raising:

SCRIPT: **Terrainmodifier**

```
    public void RaiseTerrain(Terrain terrain, Vector3 location, float effectIncrement)
{
    int offset = areaOfEffectSize / 2;

    //--1--
    Vector3 tempCoord = (location - terrain.GetPosition());
    Vector3 coord;

    coord = new Vector3(
        (tempCoord.x / GetTerrainSize().x),
        (tempCoord.y / GetTerrainSize().y),
        (tempCoord.z / GetTerrainSize().z)
        );

    Vector3 locationInTerrain = new Vector3(coord.x * terrainHeightMapWidth, 0, coord.z * terrainHeightMapHeight);
    // End --1--

    // --2--
    int terX = (int)locationInTerrain.x - offset;
    int terZ = (int)locationInTerrain.z - offset;
    // End --2--

    // --3--
    float[,] heights = targetTerrainData.GetHeights(terX, terZ, areaOfEffectSize, areaOfEffectSize);

    for (int xx = 0; xx < areaOfEffectSize; xx++)
    {
        for (int yy = 0; yy < areaOfEffectSize; yy++)
        {
            heights[xx, yy] += (effectIncrement * Time.smoothDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    targetTerrainData.SetHeights(terX, terZ, heights);
}
```

So I thought I could use this as an aid and transfer it. So I took **GetAlphamaps()** instead of **GetHeights()** and added the variable **areaOfEffectSize**.

SCRIPT: **TerrainPainter**

```
    void Paint(Vector3 point)
{

    // --1--
    mapX = (int)(((point.x - terrainPosition.x) / terrainData.size.x) * heightmapWidth);
    mapY = (int)(((point.z - terrainPosition.z) / terrainData.size.z) * heigtmapHeight);
    // End --1--

    // --2--
    int terX = (int)mapX - (areaOfEffectSize / 2);
    int terY = (int)mapY - (areaOfEffectSize / 2);
    // End --2--

    // --3--
    splatmapData = terrainData.GetAlphamaps(terX, terY, areaOfEffectSize, areaOfEffectSize);

    for(int xx = 0; xx < areaOfEffectSize; xx++)
    {
        for (int yy = 0; yy < areaOfEffectSize; yy++)
        {
            splatmapData[yy, xx, 1] = element[0, 0, 1] = 1;
        }
    }
    terrain.terrainData.SetAlphamaps(terX, terY, element);
}
```

Hope sb can help me find my mistake. How can I change the size of my "brush"?

**EDIT**: I wrote comments into the code to see the transfered/related lines.

Comment: "But it doesn't work" is a little vague. Please state what you expect it to do, and what it does.

Comment: Hey, I wanted to change the size of my "brush". So I also created a variable areaOfEffectSize and used GetAlphamaps, because in my Terrainmodifier-Script I used GetHeights. But it still draws with the same thickness/size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh guys, I did a stupid mistake. Solved this problem by passing the splatmapData into SetAlphamaps -.-
So the solution is:

[..]

```
        for (int xx = 0; xx < areaOfEffectSize; xx++)
    {
        for (int yy = 0; yy < areaOfEffectSize; yy++)
        {
            splatmapData[yy, xx, 0] = 0;
            splatmapData[yy, xx, 1] = 1;
        }
    }
    terrain.terrainData.SetAlphamaps(terX, terY, splatmapData);
```